# Convert any attribute from org.bson.Document to JSON

Tags: java, json, mongodb, object, instance

I've org.bson.Document objects and I need to retrieve some attributes and convert them to JSON (String).

```
public String example(Document doc){
    Object obj = doc.get("key");
    // the object can be a string, long, document, arrayList...
    // I need to return a JSON String
    return obj.toString();
}
```

Is there any simple way to achieve this without using "instance of"?
The result of "get" is an object that could be an ArrayList, a String, a Long, a Document...

EDIT: So far, the best I achieved was something like this...

```
public String example(Document doc){
    Object obj = new JSONObject(doc.toJson()).opt("key");
    return obj!=null ? obj.toString():"";
}
```

It works but I assume it has some overhead, is there a better way?

Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This is how to convert Document to JSONObject:

```
Document doc = ...;
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(doc.get("key", Map.class));
```

Then you can get string:

```
object.toJSONString()
```